# How can the CAPTCHA process be more user friendly or better implemented?

Tags: user-interface, captcha, presentation

I have used [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) on my various web sites in the [standard manner](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CaptchaImage.aspx) where I generated some obfuscated string of characters (odd pair of words, random number, etc.) in an image for the user to manually reproduce in a text box.  I am also aware of [recaptcha.net](http://recaptcha.net/) which extends the basic functionality of screening bots from humans and as well as helping to digitize books.  I just came across another way of performing CAPTCHA with the [AJAX Fancy CAPTCHA jQuery plugin](http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin) which rather than asking the user to reproduce a string instead asks the user to drag an image that is readily recognizable (scissors, pencil, book, etc.) into an area that is equally recognizable.  When I saw this I had to say to myself "WOW...that's cool!"

**Question:** Does anyone out there have any other examples of a neat and different way of performing CAPTCHA without having to generate a random string of characters into an image for the user to *try and read* (or regenerate until they can) so that they can manually type it into a box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to see ReCAPTCHA implemented for images that a computer can't tell whether or not they're pornography. Web filter companies could pay free porn sites to use this system to better fill out their blacklists. The free porn sites could then make more porn, and the web filters would have more porn to block.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am not particularly helpful in this answer, feel free to downvote me if it's the case, but I want to present my technical opinion (albeit of a non-expert) on captchas.

As someone said, the captcha is an antipattern of the web. Its purpose is to let you demonstrate that you are human, by doing something that only a human (purposely) can do.
Fact is that, despite the captchas, the only achieved result has been to improve pattern recognition for software, producing better bots. In this sense, it can be said that the final, real purpose of captchas was not to select humans from bots, but select better bots (or cheap workers) from lousy ones.

What you are asking is actually a matter of current research. I've seen stuff like [selecting cats from dogs](http://www.captchathedog.com/), solving simple math problems, recognizing apples from oranges, counting the number of people in a photo, but in the end I doubt you will get something more proficient or user friendly than what's currently available. In the end, the pure fact of having to solve a captcha is user-unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your users tell dogs and cats apart. [Microsoft's Asirra.](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/)

Comment: Oh yes...this is exactly what I was looking for.  A non-subjective test that tells you straight away if this is a person or not...but using subject matter that is of a true/false nature.  In general it would be very difficult for one to confuse a cat from a dog.  I can see so many other forms of this in my mind.

Comment: @Stefano Borini - This does help to both prove and disprove your point "In this sense, it can be said that the final, real purpose of captchas was not to select humans from bots, but select better bots (or cheap workers) from lousy ones."  This form of CAPTCHA (asirra) would very easily remove all bot fluff.  However it would not remove the "cheap worker" concept!

Comment: It will remove it until someone either finds a way to let a computer distinguish between dog and cats, or they crack the captcha so to override it in some way. In this sense, it is an eternal fight.

Comment: A bot would still be able to guess the CAPTCHA 50% of the time, so that idea is pointless.

Comment: Since the service has you figure out multiple pictures, (not just 2), the percent is way less then 50%. Second, if you looked on the site, it says that studies have shown it is hard for computers to tell cats and dogs apart, but easy for humans.

Comment: Looks like MS took the idea from the old Kitten Auth project. 

As a side note I made the suggestion to Stack Overflow that they adopt some sort of image based authentication but they like captcha.

Comment: In studies, 8 out of 10 bots prefer whiskas.

Answer (score 0):

A CAPTCHA should be a last resort, having tried other alternatives. For example you can use [a honeypot technique,](http://www.ngenworks.com/blog/detail/invisible_captcha_to_prevent_form_spam/) that uses a form field that’s invisible to a user but visible to a bot – if it gets filled in, you know it’s not from a human.

In some cases you can experiment with softer CAPTCHAs like riddles or simple math problems. The best tactic - from a User Experience perspective - is to start as soft as possible, and only ramp up if bots become a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Friendly Captcha? It solves the puzzle by itself (without specific input by the user). The user only has to interact with the page (moving the mouse, jumping between input fields) and the puzzle will be resolved bit by bit.